# Double closure fails in GSP

Tags: grails, closures, gsp

In a GSP file I write something like this:

```
${tgs.singleGameSheets.find{it.matchnumber==1}.awayPlayer.fullname()}
```

But I receive the following error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed:
>   C__STS_Projekte_TischtennisManager_grails_app_views_league__showGameSheet_gsp:
>   49:expecting '}', found ')' @ line 49, column 134.
>   heets.find{it.matchnumber==1 })

The problem seems to be the double closure as I've found a bug report [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7180).

Unfortunately the solution from the bugreport with the `%=` and `%` at the beginning and the end of the tag is not working for me.

Are there any other workarounds or solutions for this double closure problem?

I'm using Grails 1.3.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to split this up in to two lines.

Try assigning the find results to a separate var first

```
<% def r = tgs.singleGameSheets.find{it.matchnumber==1} %>
${r*.awayPlayer.fullname()}
```

Comment: great, it works, but without  the * in 'r*' because "find" return a single object, not a list. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool - sorry, I'm used to dealing with findAll more often, and * is my default keystrokes :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend firstly to do this sort of data processing in the controller and hand data that is as well prepared as possible down to the view.

If you are unable to do that, I would recommend trying to use parenthesis:

```
${tgs.singleGameSheets.find{it.matchnumber==1}.awayPlayer.fullname()}
```

becomes

```
${(tgs.singleGameSheets.find{it.matchnumber==1}.awayPlayer.fullname())}
```

That has worked for me on past occasions where I had to do `${(someCollection.findAll { someClause })}`